# Preseleccionar un dato vuejs html

Tags: html5, select, html-select, vuejs

favor me ayudan con lo siguiente, estoy realizando un select y necesito preseleccionar uno

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="app">
<select class="form-control" name="template" v-model="items.name">
    <option v-for="item in items"
        :selectd="item.id == 1"
        value="{{item.name}}">
        {{item.name}}
    </option>
</select>

    <pre>{{ items | json}}</pre>

</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="vuejs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi vue js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      {id: 1, name: 'Kike'},
      {id: 2, name: 'lee'},
      {id: 3, name: 'seba'},
    ]
  },
})
```

¿ Como puedo preseleccionar el item con la id 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te conviene guardar el valor seleccionado en una variable, `selected` por ejemplo.

Entonces, si le podés poner como valor a cada option la `id`,  directamente le asignás el valor al crear la variable.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      selected: '1',
      items: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Kike'},
        {id: 2, name: 'lee'},
        {id: 3, name: 'seba'},
      ]
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">

    <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.id">
        {{ item.name }}
    </option>
    </select>
    <span>value: {{ selected }}</span>
    
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

Si el valor es uno de los atributos, como `name`, en la función mounted, podés asignar al valor, el atributo `name` del objeto que tiene 1 como `id`.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      selected: '',
      items: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Kike'},
        {id: 2, name: 'lee'},
        {id: 3, name: 'seba'},
      ]
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.selected = this.items.find(obj => obj.id == 1).name;
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">

    <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.name">
        {{ item.name }}
    </option>
    </select>
    <span>value: {{ selected }}</span>
    
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

O si querés manejar todo el objeto en el valor, en la función mounted, podés asignar el objeto que tiene 1 como `id`.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      selected: {},
      items: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Kike'},
        {id: 2, name: 'lee'},
        {id: 3, name: 'seba'},
      ]
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.selected = this.items.find(obj => obj.id == 1);
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">

    <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="item in items" :value="item">
        {{ item.name }}
    </option>
    </select>
    <span>value: {{ selected }}</span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```